# How to db:seed my acts-as-taggable-on tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am trying to create a numerous amount of tags inside of my database, does anyone know how to do this with the gem [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)?

Products table:

```
create_table :products do |t|
   t.string :name
   t.date :date
   t.decimal  :price, :default => 0, :precision => 10, :scale => 2
   t.integer :user_id
end
```

and the **`:tag_list` field is a virtual column** created by the migration of `ActsAsTaggableOn`:

```
class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.string :name
    end

    create_table :taggings do |t|
      t.references :tag

      # You should make sure that the column created is
      # long enough to store the required class names.
      t.references :taggable, :polymorphic => true
      t.references :tagger, :polymorphic => true

      t.string :context

      t.datetime :created_at
    end

    add_index :taggings, :tag_id
    add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :taggings
    drop_table :tags
  end
end
```

This is my `:tag_list` field in my **products/form.html.erb**

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tag_list %>:
    <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
</div>
```

I tried to do something like this....

```
Product.create([
  {:tag_list => 'Foods'},
  {:tag_list => 'Electronics'},
  {:tag_list => 'Pizza'},
  {:tag_list => 'Groceries'},
  {:tag_list => 'Walmart'},
  {:tag_list => 'Apples'},
  {:tag_list => 'Oranges'} ])
```

But my lack of RoR skill tells me this is the wrong way and that i need help, any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this in your seeds.rb:

```
list = ['tag 1', 'tag 2', ...]

list.each do |tag|
  ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.new(:name => tag).save
end
```

Obviously substitute the values of the list array for your desired tags.

Note: this will just populate the tags table.  I hope that is what you were looking for.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might create some test products in your seeds file using something like this:

```
unless Rails.env.production?
  1..20.times.each do |n|
    Product.create(
      name: "Some product #{n}",
      date: Date.today - n.days,
      price: 1_000_000 + n,
      user: User.first
    )
  end
end
```

So you could seed tags by doing this

```
# ...
  product = Product.create(
    # ...
  )
  product.tag_list.add "tag1", "tag2"
  product.save
# ...
```

Or

```
# ...
  Product.create(
    # ...
  ).tap do |product|
    product.tag_list.add "tag1", "tag2"
    product.save
  end
# ...
```